# F#: What are the valid prefix operators?

Tags: f#

Is there a list of valid prefix operator names somewhere? I haven't been able to find one, but I've noticed that some operators that used to be valid as prefix operators in the last CTP are no longer valid in the RC.

```
let (~--) (str:string) = [str];;
-----^^^

stdin(4,6): error FS1208: Invalid operator definition. 
Prefix operator definitions must use a valid prefix operator name.
```

Edit:

Brian's link includes the following list of valid prefix operators:

```
! (or repetitions of !)
~ (or repetitions of ~)
+
-
+.
-.
%
%%
&
&&
```

My link below lists only these operators:

```
~
!
?
```

A quick test shows that the MSDN docs do not seem to be current with the language spec. Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc245030784

which spells out the rules.  I've quoted some of it below.  (See also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228(VS.100).aspx

but I think it doesn't have the full rules.)

The following symbolic-op tokens can be used to form expressions:

```
infix-op :=
    or || & && <OP >OP $OP = |OP &OP ^OP :: -OP +OP *OP /OP %OP 
    **OP

infix-or=prefix-op :=
    -OP +OP % %% & &&

prefix-op :=
    ! (or repetitions of !)
    ~ (or repetitions of ~) 
    +
    -
    +.
    -.
    %
    %%
    &
    &&
```

Operators made of the following are always prefix operators:

- repeated !
- repeated ~

Other operators beginning with these characters are not permitted.

The operators +,  -, +., -., %, &, && and may be used as both prefix and infix operators.  When used as prefix operators these operators have an implicit operator name with ~ prepended. For example, -x is parsed as an application of the operator ~- to the expression x. This name is also used when giving definitions for these prefix operators:

This means that these prefix operators are defined with the ~ character added:

```
// For a complete redefinition of the operator:
let (~+) x = x

// For defining the operator on a type:
type C(n:int) =
    let n = n % 7
    member x.N = n
    static member (~+) (x:C) = x
    static member (~-) (x:C) = C(-n)
    static member (+) (x1:C,x2:C) = C(x1.N+x2.N)
    static member (-) (x1:C,x2:C) = C(x1.N-x2.N)
```

Answer (score 22):

There are two types of prefix operators: tilde-prefixed operators and bang-prefixed operators. Tilde-prefixed operators start with a tilde "~" and bang-prefixed operators start with a bang "!". The main difference is that you omit the tilde character when you apply a tilde-prefixed operator.

### Tilde-prefixed operators

A tilde-prefixed operator begins with a tilde "~" followed by one of these:
+, -, +., -., %, %%, &, &&

A tilde-prefixed operator can also be build as a list of any numbers of tildes:
~~, ~~~, ~~~~, ~~~~~, ...

When you apply the operator you have to omit the tilde unless it is a tilde snake.

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ declaration ║   usage    ║         remark           ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ ~~          ║ ~~         ║                          ║
║ ~~~         ║ ~~~        ║                          ║
║ ~~~~~~~~~   ║ ~~~~~~~~~  ║ or any number of tildes  ║
║ ~+          ║ +          ║                          ║
║ ~+.         ║ +.         ║                          ║
║ ~-          ║ -          ║                          ║
║ ~-.         ║ -.         ║                          ║
║ ~%          ║ %          ║                          ║
║ ~%%         ║ %%         ║                          ║
║ ~&          ║ &          ║                          ║
║ ~&&         ║ &&         ║                          ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

### Bang-prefixed operators

A bang-prefixed operator begins with a bang "!" followed by any combination of these characters:
!, %, &, *, +, ., /, <, =, >, @, ^, |, ~, ?

The exception of this rule is "!=". A prefix operator must not begin with this combination.

This table lists some examples.

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ declaration  ║    usage     ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ !!           ║ !!           ║
║ !%           ║ !%           ║
║ !&           ║ !&           ║
║ !*           ║ !*           ║
║ !+           ║ !+           ║
║ !.           ║ !.           ║
║ !/           ║ !/           ║
║ !<           ║ !<           ║
║ !>           ║ !>           ║
║ !@           ║ !@           ║
║ !^           ║ !^           ║
║ !|           ║ !|           ║
║ !~           ║ !~           ║
║ !?           ║ !?           ║
║ !@=@>        ║ !@=@>        ║
║ !!!/<=>@!!!* ║ !!!/<=>@!!!* ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

### Code snippet tilde-prefixed operators

```
type SomeString = SomeString of string

let ( ~~  ) (SomeString s) = "~~ "  + s
let ( ~~~ ) (SomeString s) = "~~~ " + s
let ( ~~~~~~~~~ ) (SomeString s) = "~~~~~~~~~ " + s
let ( ~+  ) (SomeString s) = "~+ "  + s
let ( ~+. ) (SomeString s) = "~+. " + s
let ( ~-  ) (SomeString s) = "~- "  + s
let ( ~-. ) (SomeString s) = "~-. " + s
let ( ~%  ) (SomeString s) = "~% "  + s
let ( ~%% ) (SomeString s) = "~%% " + s
let ( ~&  ) (SomeString s) = "~& "  + s
let ( ~&& ) (SomeString s) = "~&& " + s

let x = SomeString "tilde"

printf "%s\n" (~~  x)           // ~~ tilde
printf "%s\n" (~~~ x)           // ~~~ tilde
printf "%s\n" (~~~~~~~~~ x)     // ~~~~~~~~~ tilde
printf "%s\n" (+  x)            // ~+ tilde      
printf "%s\n" (+. x)            // ~+. tilde
printf "%s\n" (-  x)            // ~- tilde
printf "%s\n" (-. x)            // ~-. tilde
printf "%s\n" (%  x)            // ~% tilde
printf "%s\n" (%% x)            // ~%% tilde
printf "%s\n" (&  x)            // ~& tilde
printf "%s\n" (&& x)            // ~&& tilde
```

### Code snippet bang-prefixed operators

```
type SomeString = SomeString of string

let ( !! ) (SomeString s) = "!! " + s
let ( !% ) (SomeString s) = "!% " + s 
let ( !& ) (SomeString s) = "!& " + s 
let ( !* ) (SomeString s) = "!* " + s 
let ( !+ ) (SomeString s) = "!+ " + s 
let ( !. ) (SomeString s) = "!. " + s 
let ( !/ ) (SomeString s) = "!/ " + s 
let ( !< ) (SomeString s) = "!< " + s 
let ( !> ) (SomeString s) = "!> " + s
let ( !@ ) (SomeString s) = "!@ " + s 
let ( !^ ) (SomeString s) = "!^ " + s 
let ( !| ) (SomeString s) = "!| " + s 
let ( !~ ) (SomeString s) = "!~ " + s 
let ( !? ) (SomeString s) = "!? " + s 
let ( !@=@> ) (SomeString s) = "@=@> " + s 
let ( !!!/<=>@!!!* ) (SomeString s) = "!!!/<=>@!!!* " + s 
//let ( != )   (SomeString s) = "!= " + s   // prefix != is not allowed
//let ( !=@@ ) (SomeString s) = "!= " + s   // prefix != is not allowed

let y = SomeString "bang"

printf "%s\n" (!! y)            // !! bang
printf "%s\n" (!% y)            // !% bang
printf "%s\n" (!& y)            // !& bang
printf "%s\n" (!* y)            // !* bang     
printf "%s\n" (!+ y)            // !+ bang
printf "%s\n" (!. y)            // !. bang
printf "%s\n" (!/ y)            // !/ bang
printf "%s\n" (!< y)            // !< bang
printf "%s\n" (!> y)            // !> bang
printf "%s\n" (!@ y)            // !@ bang
printf "%s\n" (!^ y)            // !^ bang
printf "%s\n" (!| y)            // !| bang
printf "%s\n" (!~ y)            // !~ bang
printf "%s\n" (!? y)            // !? bang
printf "%s\n" (!@=@> y)         // !@=@> bang
printf "%s\n" (!!!/<=>@!!!* y)  // !!!/<=>@!!!* bang
```

Comment: This is an excellent summary! It also explains several of the issues in the docs that are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I think I [found the list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204(VS.100).aspx), in the second table under the "Overloaded Operator Names" heading.