# How to define x++ (where x: int ref) in F#?

Tags: f#, operators

I currently use this function

```
let inc (i : int ref) =
    let res = !i
    i := res + 1
    res
```

to write things like

```
let str = input.[inc index]
```

How define increment operator ++, so that I could write

```
let str = input.[index++]
```

Comment: One question: why do you need this?

Comment: I'm with @pad on this one - while the question is valid, and an answer has been provided (as a prefix operator), the example given here is not F# style at all. Rarely a good reason to do something like this.

Comment: I wanted that for readability. (I come from C++/C# background). I though it was possible but couldn't make it myself.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-ii-break.aspx).

Comment: @modosansreves "I wanted that for readability". You're doing it wrong. Describe the actual problem you are trying to solve using mutating increment in C++ if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot define postfix operators in F# - see [4.4 Operators and Precedence](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997017). If you agree to making it prefix instead, then you can define, for example,

```
let (++) x = incr x; !x
```

and use it as below:

```
let y = ref 1
(++) y;;

val y : int ref = {contents = 2;}
```

**UPDATE**: as [fpessoa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339358/fpessoa) pointed out `++` **cannot** be used as a genuine prefix operator, indeed (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204%28VS.100%29.aspx) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304141/917053) for the rules upon characters and character sequences comprising valid F# prefix operators).

Interestingly, the unary `+` can be overloaded for the purpose:

```
let (~+) x = incr x; !x
```

allowing

```
let y = ref 1
+y;;

val y : int ref = {contents = 2;}
```

Nevertheless, it makes sense to mention that the idea of iterating an array like below

```
let v = [| 1..5 |] 
let i = ref -1 
v |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> printfn "%d" v.[+i])
```

for the sake of "readability" looks at least strange in comparison with the idiomatic functional manner

```
[|1..5|] |> Seq.iter (printfn "%d")
```

which some initiated already had expressed in comments to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to write it as a prefix operator as suggested, but you can't define (++) as a proper prefix operator, i.e., run things like ++y without the () as you could for example for (!+):

```
let (!+) (i : int ref) = incr i; !i

let v = [| 1..5 |]
let i = ref -1
[1..5] |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> printfn "%d" v.[!+i])
```

Sorry, but I guess the answer is that actually you can't do even that.