# Custom prefix operators in F# once again

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

No matter how many times I read this post: [F#: What are the valid prefix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304120/f-what-are-the-valid-prefix-operators)

Me and the F# compiler never agrees on what are custom prefix (or infix) operator names.

In the above post it says that "+" can be both an infix and prefix operator, but this:

```
let (+@) a = a + 20
+@ 30 |> printfn "%d"
```

gives the error "Invalid prefix operator".

Why?

Comment: There are left and right-associative operators. And in-,pre-,post-fix operators. The rule is simple. If you create an operator before midnight it is left-associative, after midnight it is right. If you are Human it is infix, for Werewolves it is prefix, and vampires only creates postfix. But Vampires with blood type AB+ are also infix like humans. Werewolfs that creates operators at full-moon are also infix, but humans at full-moons are prefix. On a 13th friday in a month, all operators are postfix. Vampires cannot use "~". That is how i understand operator definitions in F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll look through Brian's answer in the link you provided you'll find that operator `+@` is not listed among `prefix-op`. And to be used as **prefix** operator, the operator `+` should be prepended by `~`:

```
let (~+) a = a + 20
+ 30 |> printfn "%d"
```

Result:

> 50

Comment: I'm really lost. I understand that I need to add '~' before '+' to make it prefix, but then why doesn't '~+@' work? '!@' works fine. The OP suffix seems to have different constraints depending on what comes before them? Where is this documented?

Comment: I think it is documented in the specs:http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/ Section 4.4 Operators and Precedence