# F# Cast as Prefix Operator

Tags: casting, f#, operators

In F#, many infix operators can be made prefix operators:

```
a + b
(+) 1 a b
```

However, this doesn’t seem to be allowed for the upcast (or downcast) operators.

`x` is a `UserPrincipal`, which inherits from `Principal`

```
x :> Principal
(:>) x Principal
```

Why?

Comment: [Duplicate question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304120/f-what-are-the-valid-prefix-operators)

Comment: Note that even though it's not a prefix operator, it still works nicely with pipelining. (looks like I can't format a code example in a comment).

Comment: @JimFoye I am using a lambda: `principals |> Array.map (fun x -> x :?> UserPrincipal)`. Is there a more elegant way to do this? When pipelining, the input becomes the last argument, but the last argument to `:?>` is the type.

Comment: You could use cast: principals |> Seq.cast<UserPrincipal>

Comment: This is lovely. Available in C# as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because unlike other operators, the cast operators don't take two expressions as arguments; they take an expression and a type. So `(:>) x` would have to be "a function that takes a type", which is not a thing that exists in F#.